# PHP Session Cookie gets deleted

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

It seems that when I try to keep my session cookie, it deletes itself on browser close.  The cookie params are set for a lifetime of 0.  But when I go in to check it out, the cookie is not there.  What is going on here?

Comment: when you set lifetime at 0, cookie is deleted when you close your browser

Answer (score 2):

If its lifetime is set to 0, the cookie deletes itself when closing the browser.
If you want to keep it alive for longer, you need to specify a time, such as 5h or 12m oder 8y.

Use something like this for the time value:

```
time()+60*60*24*30
```

In this case the cookie would last 30 days (60-seconds * 60-minutes * 24-hours * 30-days)

Answer (score 2):

when you set lifetime at 0, cookie is deleted when you close your browser

try set a fix value and you should fix your problem.

source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php